# Trine 1 and 2 close right after launch

Tags: steam, trine-2, trine

I bought Trine 1 and 2 on steam and when I opened it didn't work.

The launcher with the graphics configurations, language and Mods opens normaly, but when I try to launch, the game close itself right after I launch and no error message are displayed.

What I already tried:

- install and reinstall DirectX and components;
- Reinstall the game;
- Verify the game repository for corrupted files;
- And several others basics like: run as admin, windows compatibility mods, etc.

I use windows 10 x64.

Has anyone had this problem and figured out how to fix it?

EDIT: when I try to open direct from the game folder i get the 0xc000007b error.

Comment: Check your event viewer for fatal errors and research those error codes.